# Where to get critiques?

Tags: resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Internet communities where I can read/rate/review short fiction, and post my own?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/internet-communities-where-i-can-read-rate-review-short-fiction-and-post-my-own)

Where can I get feedback on my writing? I have just begun learning about writing novels and I need somewhere which is 100% free and has a high quality of critiques. I'm not sure if this website is the right place for this (I have asked a lot of programming questions on StackOverflow for example, but I've never asked for *code review*).